# xmlhttprequest on IOS not sending Request?

Tags: javascript, ios, soap, xmlhttprequest, filemaker

I am working on a filemaker project. In this project I need to make requests to a soap service. To do so I use a web viewer in Filemaker. From the web viewer I make a soap request and then, using the filemaker fmp:// protocol I can send data from the web viewer to my database for further processing.

To make this work I will load an HTML page into the web viewer.
I have the following local html page, containing a script that communicates with the soap service:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
</head>
<body>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var req = ' --- request comes here ----';
xhr.open('POST', 'https://--- soapservice endpoint ---', true, '***_***_***', '******');
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0) {
      alert ('Onload responsetext: ' + xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      alert ('Onload statustext: ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};


xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  alert ('onerror statustext: ' + xhr.statusText + ',status: ' + xhr.status);
};
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '');
xhr.send(req);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this page in Safari, on my Imac, the script works fine and I get a response from the server.

On my Ipad IOS I don't get a response from the server. xhr.Status = 0 and readyState = 4 and responseText is empty.
If I put an onreadystatechange function in de script that will alert on every ready state change (1 to 4) I only get alerts from ready state 1 and Ready state 4.

The on error function is triggered giving an alert status 0 and empty status text

Because it is not a public server I cannot post the actual url
The username has two "_" in it.

Why is this code not working in IOS ???

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. IMHO, you would be much better off **importing** the records directly from the response, using an XSLT stylesheet to transform the response to Filemaker's XML grammar.

Comment: Importing xml files is not possible using filemaker Go. I'am trying to make this database work on my Ipad.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right about that. How about Insert From URL[], would that work for you?

Comment: Insert from url doesn't handle authentication. I connect to a thirdparty server that uses username and password.

Comment: I found that the concept is working, as long as I am doing the soaprequest from localhost. So its more of a filemaker thing than a javascript problem. ReBuilding step by step now to find where the problem coms from.

Comment: "*Insert from url doesn't handle authentication.*" Are you sure about that? I can't test this myself, but isn't a POST request a POST request?

Comment: I agree, a post is a post but, there is no way I know of, to give username and password using Insert from URL. There are plug-ins, but they don't work in Filemaker GO.

Comment: Can't it be done the way it's described here? http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/non_toc.46.34.html#1079151 As I said, I don't know myself and I'd be glad to find out.

Comment: Taht is the way you would use a insert from URL script step. Trouble is that there is no way of changing the headers. I need to add the "soap action' header. I'm not sure if my last comment was correct about not being able to authenticate. I am sure that I am not able to change the header info. see : http://www.databuzz.com.au/filemaker-pro-13-http-post-and-http-headers/

Comment: I see. Apparently, a POST request is not always a POST request after all. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is working on IOS, filemaker GO. there is no problem with the javascript code. For some reason the Webviewer in Filemaker is not running the script on Filemaker GO in my main database app. It is running in my test database ???

Found a solution: For some reason the web viewer was not loading the data url on my Ipad. This was fixed by inserting a script step "refresh window". Don't ask me why, but it fixed the problem.